# ROS Answers SE migration: Creating a map

Tags: navigation, mapping, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone
let say that i want turtlebot to navigate certain area but i dont wanna run gmapping.it just call the map for that area and navigate.how can i create the map if i dont want to use gazebo etc.?is it possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191769/creating-a-map/) by [lfyhmdn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20052/lfyhmdn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [offline data](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData#Downloading_a_test_bag) with  [rosbag](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag)  to create the map with `gmapping` or `hector mapping` . Later you can load the map and can navigate using [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl).

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lfyhmdn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20052/lfyhmdn/) on 2014-09-09**:
noted..thanks for the information..by the way, is it possible to create map (by editing the yaml file) straight away from a picture or real map?i mean translating the picture into yaml file by using some sort of algorithm..is it do able?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-09**:
yes you can try that by [converting your map image](http://www.office-converter.com/JPG-to-PGM) to `.pgm` and create `.yaml` manually,